# angular enabling paging from a local json file

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to set up a service that, when I feel like it, I can flip to live data coming from an API. The getData function takes skip/take parameters to define start record and number of records.

My data is currently in a json file:

```
{
    "Data":[{
        "Id":"1462",
        "Name":"Cynthia"

    },{
        "Id":"1463",
        "Name":"Bob"
    },{
        ...
    }],
    "Total":71
}
```

My service currently pulls all json data at once:

```
    var _getData = function (optionsData) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'data/packages.json'
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        },
            function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
```

It seems to me that I have to write the paging logic right into the service:

```
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            var records = response.data.Data;
            var firstRecord = 0;//optionsData.skip;
            var numberOfRecords = 1;//optionsData.take;
            response.data.Data = records.slice(firstRecord, firstRecord + numberOfRecords);
            return response;
        },
```

Is this the right way in principle?

[ UPDATE ] The controller method:

```
     var getPackageData = function (options){
        return dataService.getData(options.data).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                options.success(response.data.Data);
                $scope.totalCount = response.data.Total;
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                // handle error
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: P.S. I know there are mock data modules. They're kind of overkill for a demo.

Comment: The errorCallback is **converting** a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise. And no, iterative extractions from a promise don't have to be done in the service. The `.then` method can be used as many times as one wants.

Comment: my errorCallback is wrong? How? It's gonig to pass back to my front end methods: successCallback(response) and errorCallback(response)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would make use of multiple .thens here. How does this help what I'm doing?

Comment: I am wondering if I should split the functiality into 2 services. #1 permanent and generic, with a simple switch between local and remote. #2 would only be called when in local mode - to do the local data massaging.

Answer (score 0):

> my errorCallback is wrong? How?

The `errorCallback` is **converting** a *rejected* promise to a *fulfilled* promise.

To avoid conversion, either `throw` the response or `return $q.reject`:

```
var _getData = function (optionsData) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'data/packages.json'
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    },
        function errorCallback(response) {
        //To avoid converting reject to success
        //DON'T
        //return response;
        //INSTEAD
        throw response;
        //OR
        //return $q.reject(response);
    });
}
```

Another common error is to fail to include either a `throw` or `return` statement. When a function omits a return statement, the function returns a value of `undefined`. In that case, the `$q` service will **convert** rejected promises to fulfilled promises which yield a value of `undefined`.